# Using LINQ to set up a login page from an access database

Tags: vb.net, linq, ms-access

I currently have a small table of 4 records of people in an Access Database each with just three fields, Role, Username and Password. Im trying to set up a login page where I'm using LINQ to read the Username and Password fields and then if they are both correct then to login to one of 4 possible roles depending on what role that person is allocated to on database. I currently have this.

```
Private Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
        Dim strUsername As String
        Dim strPassword As String
        Dim strRole As String

        Dim query1 = From loginUsername In database1.tblStaff
                     Where loginUsername.FirstName = txtUsername.Text
                     Select loginUsername.FirstName

        Dim query2 = From loginPassword In database1.tblStaff
                     Where loginPassword.Password = txtPassword.Text
                     Select loginPassword.Password


    End Sub
End Class
```

As you can see, I'm trying to take what the user enters in each text box and match it to the database and then somehow set up an if statement checking if it's right but I'm not sure if I'm even on the right track.

Any help is great, thanks.

Comment: LINQ is used to query a collection of objects that supports IEnumerable. If `tblStaff` is a DataTable, then you wouldn't be able to use LINQ.

Comment: okay , what way would you recommend trying to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [login form using ms access in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326131/login-form-using-ms-access-in-vb-net)

Comment: @ChrisRyan - it depends. Do you really want to use LINQ or are you acceptable with an alternative that was used pre-3.5?

Comment: Im not pushed on using LINQ, I just thought that might be an easy way to do it. If possible I'd like to do it using a binding source instead of connecting the database with code

Comment: *"I'd like to do it using a binding source instead of connecting the database with code"*. That's a nonsensical statement. A `BindingSource` is not magic. Is is a link between a data source and one or more UI controls. You have to have a data source in the first place, e.g. a `DataTable`, and you obviously have to connect to a database with code to retrieve the data with which to populate it. It doesn't make sense to retrieve all the data for every user just to check one record when someone logs in. Do the appropriate query on each login.

Comment: If you are using LINQ this way then you are presumably using Entity Framework and the LINQ to Entities provider. You should have made a firm decision on data access technology by now. If you would rather use ADO.NET than EF then make that decision now and stick to it. In that case, you'd create an `OleDbCommand` and call `ExecuteScalar` to get a single `Role` value based on login credentials. It's basically the same thing but written slightly differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it should be something like this (disclaimer: I'm not familiar with VB)

```
Dim role = (From entry In database1.tblStaff
            Where entry .FirstName = txtUsername.Text
            AndAlso entry.Password = txtPassword.Text
            Select entry.Role)
           .FirstOrDefault()  'execute query explicitly

'if a role is null, then login or password incorrect
If role Is Nothing Then
    'No match
Else
    'Use role here
End If
```

There is no point to separate queries. You can merge them in a single query

Comment: You should be using `AndAlso` rather than `&&`, which is the C# short-circuiting Boolean operator and `=` rather than `==`, which doesn't exist in VB, but the rest is correct. I thought that there was more wrong in your query before I wrote my answer. I reread your code afterwards and it's better than I thought. The OP obviously didn't get the check after correct though.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you sm Chris this has been a lifesaver for Yvonne's project! Our group was really struggling with this. You probably already have you answer by now, that code works really well. You just have to add your If statements after:

```
 If query1.Count = 1 And query2.Count = 1 Then
            Me.Hide()
            FrmExample.Show()
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect username or password", "Warning")
        End If
```

Idk if that's any help, thank you!