# Using LINQ to login to a form

Tags: vb.net, linq, authentication

I've got this login form that reads the name and password from a database and then if it finds it then it will get the role associated with the name and password and log the user in. The login works however I cant get the last else if to work where it tells the user that details are entered incorrectly, no message box pops up? Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
                     Dim query1 = From entry In exampleDatabase.tblStaff
                     Where entry.FirstName = txtUsername.Text And entry.Password = txtPassword.Text
                     Select entry.Role

        For Each entry As String In query1
            If entry = "Administrator" Then
                frmAdministrator.Show()
                Me.Hide()
            ElseIf entry = "Manager" Then
                frmManager.Show()
                Me.Hide()
            ElseIf entry = "Warehouse" Then
                frmWarehouse.Show()
                Me.Hide()
            ElseIf entry = "Operator" Then
                frmOperator.Show()
                Me.Hide()
            ElseIf entry = Nothing Then
                MessageBox.Show("Username or Password Entered Wrong")
            End If

        Next
```

Comment: You probably mean `entry Is Nothing`.

Comment: You should debug your code

Comment: I have tried using the Is Nothing as well. It does not work unfortunately.

Comment: `For Each entry As String In query1` - are you expecting a user to be in more than one role? Also, are FirstName and Username really referring to the same item even though they have different variable names?

Comment: FYI to other readers, this general subject was also previously discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66753303/using-linq-to-set-up-a-login-page-from-an-access-database cc @AndrewMorton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a user can be in only one role, a [`Select...Case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/select-case-statement) statement would be better than a loop with ifs. Also, it looks like the LINQ query got a bit mangled from [the answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66754185/1115360). So...

```
Dim userRole = (From entry In exampleDatabase.tblStaff
                Where entry.FirstName = txtUsername.Text AndAlso entry.Password = txtPassword.Text
                Select entry.Role).
                FirstOrDefault()

Select Case userRole
    Case "Administrator"
        frmAdministrator.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    Case "Manager"
        frmManager.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    Case "Warehouse"
        frmWarehouse.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    Case "Operator"
        frmOperator.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    Case Else
        MessageBox.Show("Incorrect username or password.")
End Select
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the collection contains any elements:

```vb
Dim query1 = From entry In exampleDatabase.tblStaff
             Where entry.FirstName = txtUsername.Text AndAlso entry.Password = txtPassword.Text
             Select entry.Role

If (Not query1.Any()) Then
    MessageBox.Show("Username or Password Entered Wrong")
    Return
End If

query1.ForEach(Function(entry)
                   If (entry = "Administrator") Then
                       ...
                   End If
               End Function)
```